# My OBS Studio Mac OS is stuck in 9:16 aspect ratio

Tags: video, mac, obs

I'm running OBS [[[ 30.0.0 (64 bit) ]]]on Mac OS [[[ 14.2 Beta (23C5055b) ]]][image]

My only options are vertical video. This just happened and I think it's since the beta update.